# How to plot circle in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot circle using gnuplot .

I have all the information about the circle.I mean center coordinate and radius of circle is stored in a file .

That how to create circle using gnuplot by  reading data from file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third column can be used as a radius:

```
plot 'circle.txt' using 1:2:3 with circles
```

Comment: How to get full circle. I am not getting half part of circle.

Comment: @user69910: Maybe you just need to adjust the ranges?