Draw circles with assigned center and radius
a newbie question: what is the gnuplot code to drawing a circle with assigned center (x,y coordinates) and assigned radius?
For example: plot a filled black circle with center (300, 400), radius=3pixels, in a white canvas (600X600).
Thank you,
F
For now I haven't been able to find the correct way to do it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693441/1030675

Radius of 3 pixels is tiny.  I suggest to just draw a circular filled point "pointtype 7" and adjust the point size if necessary.  Gnuplot doesn't really use pixels to describe coordinates, so it would be difficult to specify the size exactly in pixels.


Gnuplot does not offer 'pixels' as a unit of coordinate measurement.  It does, however, allow you to specify coordinates as a fraction of the canvas size (gnuplot calls these "screen" coordinates).  So if you set an explicit output file size in pixels you can describe pixel measurements as a fraction of that.

3 pixels is small for a circle radius. If you selectively color whole pixels in a 6x6 grid at best you end up with something that looks like a square with the corners chopped off.  You can do a bit better than that with antialiasing, so I suggest that for such a small circle you may prefer to use an antialiased character glyphs rather than a rendered circle. I will show both below


Example code
set term pngcairo size 600,600
set output 'picture.png'

# method 1 - draw a tiny circle
# the size should come out exact but it may not look smooth
set object 1 circle at screen 0.5, screen 0.6667 radius screen 0.005
set object 1 fillstyle solid noborder fillcolor "black"

# method 2 - place a point with pointtype 7 (filled circle)
# This is a blank label with a point symbol marking its place.
# It may be smoother, but the size needs to be adjusted.
# You can adjust the exact size by changing the pointsize
set label 2 at screen 0.5, screen 0.6667 
set label 2 "" point pointtype 7 pointsize 1.0

# method 3 - place a circular character glyph rather than a circle.
# Same basic method as above except that the font rendering may do
# antialiasing to improve the apparent smoothness.  Adjust the size
# using the nominal font size of the label
set label 3 "•" font "Times,18" 
set label 3 center at screen 0.5, screen 0.6667

You still have to draw something (plot or splot command) in order to produce a graph.  The circle object or label will appear on that next plot and all subsequent plots.
